# How to create python bytes object from long hex string?

Tags: python, hex, byte

I have a long sequence of hex digits in a string, such as

> 000000000000484240FA063DE5D0B744ADBED63A81FAEA390000C8428640A43D5005BD44

only much longer, several kilobytes.  Is there a builtin way to convert this to a bytes object in python 2.6/3?

Comment: Note that the answers below may look alike but they return different types of values. s.decode('hex') returns a str, as does unhexlify(s). bytearray.fromhex(s) returns a bytearray. Given the wording of this question, I think the big green checkmark should be on bytearray.fromhex(s), not on s.decode('hex').

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hexadecimal string to byte array in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649407/hexadecimal-string-to-byte-array-in-python)

Comment: How can it be a duplicate of a question created 2 years later?

Comment: @CiroSantilli郝海东冠状病六四事件法轮功 A byte string isn't a byte array. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740696/bytes-vs-bytearray-in-python-2-6-and-3

Comment: @LarsH fair enough. @ recursive: date is not the main factor: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha

Answer (score 150, accepted):

```
result = bytes.fromhex(some_hex_string)
```

Comment: The fromhex() method (of both bytes and bytearray) will also work when the hex numbers are separated by spaces. Very convenient!

Answer (score 122):

Works in Python 2.7 and higher including python3:

```
result = bytearray.fromhex('deadbeef')
```

**Note:** There seems to be a bug with the `bytearray.fromhex()` function in Python 2.6. The python.org documentation states that the function accepts a string as an argument, but when applied, the following error is thrown:

```
>>> bytearray.fromhex('B9 01EF')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: fromhex() argument 1 must be unicode, not str`
```

Comment: And one additional step, I wanted a byte string (e.g. Python 3's b'\x04\xea[...]'), which you can get from a bytearray with `bytes(bytearray.fromhex('deadbeef'))`

Comment: @berto: in that case there is a more direct route in the form of `binascii.unhexlify()`.

Comment: This answer does not do what the question asked. It returns a mutable array of bytes, not a python bytestring. That's like returning an array of strings rather than a string.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Seems like `bytes.fromhex()` is also more direct, and a bit less obscure / more parsimonious. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex

Comment: @LarsH: that method is not available in older Python 2 releases. That doesn't matter any more today, but it was an issue in 2016.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I wondered if that was the case, but I didn't look far enough to find out.

Answer (score 46):

You can do this with the hex codec.  ie:

```
>>> s='000000000000484240FA063DE5D0B744ADBED63A81FAEA390000C8428640A43D5005BD44'
>>> s.decode('hex')
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00HB@\xfa\x06=\xe5\xd0\xb7D\xad\xbe\xd6:\x81\xfa\xea9\x00\x00\xc8B\x86@\xa4=P\x05\xbdD'
```

Comment: `codecs.decode('0a0a0a', 'hex_codec')` should work for 2.x and 3.x :-)

Answer (score 39):

Try the [binascii module](http://doc.astro-wise.org/binascii.html#-unhexlify)

```
from binascii import unhexlify
b = unhexlify(myhexstr)
```

Comment: Two ways to do it in 2.x, three ways in 3.x. So much for "there's only one way to do it"...

Comment: Other two ways are more 'built-in' so I would actually use one of those.

Comment: @technomalogical: your comment is irrelevant to the answer; perhaps you should delete it and change it into a post to comp.lang.python .

Comment: @technomalogical: I agree with ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ. Also, you got it wrong. The correct phrase is: There should be one-- and preferably only one --*obvious* way to do it.

Comment: Note that in Python 3.2 (whether by design or a bug I'm not sure) `unhexlify` now won't accept a string, but only bytes. Pretty silly really, but it means you'd need to use `b = unhexlify(bytes(myhexstr, 'utf-8'))`

Answer (score 2):

```
import binascii

binascii.a2b_hex(hex_string)
```

Thats the way I did it.