# How to convert hexadecimal string to bytes in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a long Hex string that represents a series of values of different types. I need to convert this Hex String into `bytes` or `bytearray` so that I can extract each value from the raw data. How can I do this?

For example, the string `"ab"` should convert to the bytes `b"\xab"` or equivalent byte array. Longer example:

```
>>> # what to use in place of `convert` here?
>>> convert("8e71c61de6a2321336184f813379ec6bf4a3fb79e63cd12b")
b'\x8eq\xc6\x1d\xe6\xa22\x136\x18O\x813y\xeck\xf4\xa3\xfby\xe6<\xd1+'
```

Comment: How does that hex string look like?

Answer (score 401, accepted):

Suppose your hex string is something like

```
>>> hex_string = "deadbeef"
```

#### Convert it to a bytearray (Python 3 and 2.7):

```
>>> bytearray.fromhex(hex_string)
bytearray(b'\xde\xad\xbe\xef')
```

#### Convert it to a bytes object (Python 3):

```
>>> bytes.fromhex(hex_string)
b'\xde\xad\xbe\xef'
```

Note that `bytes` is an immutable version of `bytearray`.

#### Convert it to a string (Python ≤ 2.7):

```
>>> hex_data = hex_string.decode("hex")
>>> hex_data
"\xde\xad\xbe\xef"
```

Comment: **Note** that `bytes.fromhex` throws an error when the input string has an odd number of characters: `bytes.fromhex("aab")` → `ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 3`.

Comment: The new version of `hex_string.decode("hex")` is `codecs.decode(hex_string, 'hex')`.

Answer (score 166):

There is a built-in function in bytearray that does what you intend.

```
bytearray.fromhex("de ad be ef 00")
```

It returns a bytearray and it reads hex strings with or without space separator.

Comment: The best answer for sure!

Comment: This works in Python 3, whereas `hex_string.decode("hex")` does not.

Comment: >>> bytearray.fromhex("8 ad be ef 00")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 1

Answer (score 20):

provided I understood correctly, you should look for binascii.unhexlify

```
import binascii
a='45222e'
s=binascii.unhexlify(a)
b=[ord(x) for x in s]
```

Comment: I agree that `unhexlify` is the most efficient way to go here, but would suggest that `b = bytearray(s)` would be a better than using `ord`. As Python has a built-in type just for arrays of bytes I'm surprised no one is using it

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have a byte string like so

**"\x12\x45\x00\xAB"**

and you know the amount of bytes and their type you can also use this approach

```
import struct

bytes = '\x12\x45\x00\xAB'
val = struct.unpack('<BBH', bytes)

#val = (18, 69, 43776)
```

As I specified little endian (using the '<' char) at the start of the format string the function returned the decimal equivalent.

0x12 = 18

0x45 = 69

0xAB00 = 43776

B is equal to one byte (8 bit) unsigned

H is equal to two bytes (16 bit) unsigned

[More available characters and byte sizes can be found here](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#format-characters)

**The advantages are..**

You can specify more than one byte and the endian of the values

**Disadvantages..**

You really need to know the type and length of data your dealing with

Comment: Disadvantages: that is a byte string, not a hex string, so this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: It is an answer to the 2nd part of the question "... so that I can shift each value out and convert it into its proper data type".

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Codecs module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) in the Python Standard Library, i.e.

```
import codecs

codecs.decode(hexstring, 'hex_codec')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to build a string holding the binary data using something like:

```
data = "fef0babe"
bits = ""
for x in xrange(0, len(data), 2)
  bits += chr(int(data[x:x+2], 16))
```

This is probably not the fastest way (many string appends), but quite simple using only core Python.

Answer (score -7):

A good one liner is:

```
byte_list = map(ord, hex_string)
```

This will iterate over each char in the string and run it through the ord() function.  Only tested on python 2.6, not too sure about 3.0+.

-Josh

Comment: perfect. Working on python 2.7

Comment: Click the outline of the checkmark next to this answer if it's the right one! :)

Comment: This doesn't convert hex - it converts each character of a string to an integer. For hex each pair of characters would represent a byte. You might as well just say `byte_list = bytearray(hex_string)`