# Convert a list of bytes to a byte string

Tags: python, hex, byte

I have the following list of bytes:

```
[b'S', b'\x00', b't', b'\x00', b'a', b'\x00', b'n', b'\x00', b'd', b'\x00', b'a', b'\x00', b'r', b'\x00', b'd', b'\x00', b'F', b'\x00', b'i', b'\x00', b'r', b'\x00', b'm', b'\x00', b'a', b'\x00', b't', b'\x00', b'a', b'\x00', b'.', b'\x00', b'i', b'\x00', b'n', b'\x00', b'o', b'\x00', b'y', b'\x02', b'\x03', b'S', b'\x00', b't', b'\x00', b'a', b'\x00', b'n', b'\x00', b'd', b'\x00', b'a', b'\x00', b'r', b'\x00', b'd', b'\x00', b'F', b'\x00', b'i', b'\x00', b'r', b'\x00', b'm', b'\x00', b'a', b'\x00', b't', b'\x00', b'a', b'\x00', b'.', b'\x00', b'i', b'\x00', b'n', b'\x00', b'o', b'\x00', b'y', b'\x02', b'\x03', b'S', b'\x00', b't', b'\x00', b'a', b'\x00', b'n', b'\x00', b'd', b'\x00', b'a', b'\x00', b'r', b'\x00', b'd', b'\x00', b'F', b'\x00', b'i', b'\x00', b'r', b'\x00', b'm', b'\x00', b'a', b'\x00', b't', b'\x00', b'a', b'\x00', b'.', b'\x00', b'i', b'\x00', b'n', b'\x00', b'o', b'\x00', b'y', b'\x02', b'\x03', b'S', b'\x00', b't', b'\x00', b'a', b'\x00', b'n', b'\x00', b'd', b'\x00', b'a', b'\x00', b'r',
```

Is there a simple way for me to convert that into one long `byte`? I guess techincally called a `bytestring` (though I am not sure about that).

Note, I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649407/hexadecimal-string-to-byte-array-in-python) but it does not work for me. Also, is the correct term for one long `byte` object (such as `b'\f\x04\55'`) a `byte object` or something else?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [`bytes.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.join):

```
>>> b = [b'S', b'\x00', b't', b'\x00', b'a']
>>> b''.join(b)  # b'': separator
b'S\x00t\x00a'
```

Answer (score 7):

`bytes` and `bytearray` objects have the [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.join) method:

```
In [37]: b''.join([b'S', b'\x00', b't', b'\x00', b'a', b'\x00', b'n', b'\x00', b'd', b'\x00'])
Out[37]: b'S\x00t\x00a\x00n\x00d\x00'
```