# saving hexdump(packet) to list in scapy

Tags: python, scapy, hexdump

Is there any way I could save hexdump() to byte list so the list can be accessed by index. what I need is like this

```
byte = hexdump(packet)
for i in range(0, len(byte)):
print %x byte[i]
```

Comment: Did you try using the python pickle library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The byte content of the packet may be accessed by invoking `str(packet)`, as follows:

```
content = str(packet) # decoded hex string, such as '\xde\xad\xbe\xef'
print content
for byte in content:
    pass # do something with byte
```

**EDIT -** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5682984/3903832) specifies how this can be converted to a byte array, for example:

```
byte_array = map(ord, str(packet)) # list of numbers, such as [0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF]
print byte_array
for byte in byte_array:
    pass # do something with byte
```

Comment: But i need array with hex values that i can index within the loop. for example byte [0x00, 0x11, 0x22]