# Python 2.7: TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but Ether found

Tags: python, scapy

I am constructing IGMP packet by using SCAPY Lib in Python 2.7.
And using hexdump logic in my code. But getting error while executing below code.

#### constructing scapy IGMP packet

```
ipPacket=inet.Ether(dst="01:00:5E:00:00:02",src="30:01:02:03:04:05")
/inet.IP(src="0.0.0.0",dst="224.0.0.2")/IGMP(gaddr="225.0.0.1",type=0x17)
```

#### hexdump logic

```
length = 16
FILTER = ''.join([(len(repr(chr(x))) == 3) and chr(x) or '.' for x in range(256)])
lines = []
for c in xrange(0, len(ipPacket), length):
    chars = ipPacket[c:c+length]
    hex = ' '.join(["%02x" % ord(x) for x in chars])
    printable = ''.join(["%s" % ((ord(x) <= 127 and FILTER[ord(x)]) or '.') for x in chars])
    lines.append("%04x  %-*s  %s\n" % (c, length*3, hex, printable))

payload = ''.join(lines)
```

#### Error while compilation:

```
hex = ' '.join(["%02x" % ord(x) for x in chars])
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but Ether found
```

Please let me know if anybody faced this issue before.

Comment: Possibly `ipPacket` is an instance of the `Ether` class and not a string?

Comment: Correct, but it works if I pass `ipPacket` to `hexdump`
eg, hexdump(ipPacket)

Comment: What do you mean by "compilation"?

Comment: Typo error, i mean to say 'while executing' python script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [saving hexdump(packet) to list in scapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28147515/saving-hexdumppacket-to-list-in-scapy)

Comment: I am trying to convert `ipPacket` to string format like `01005E000002300102030405 ...`