# Python3.2: string to hex to bytearrey

Tags: string, hex, type-conversion, python-3.2

I want to convert this string into a byte scheme:

```
www.google.de
```

So the output should look like:

```
\x77\x77\x77\x2e\x67\x6f\x6f\x67\x6c\x65\x2e\x64\x65\x2f\x62\x6d\x70\x2e\x62\x6d\x70
```

I tried things like:

```
a = ''.join(hex(ord(x))[2:] for x in data)
```

which gave me

```
>>> 7777772e676f6f676c65
```

I also tried:

```
b = [hex(ord(i)) for i in data[:]]
```

which resulted in:

```
>>> ['0x77', '0x77', '0x77', '0x2e', '0x67', '0x6f', '0x6f', '0x67', '0x6c', '0x65']
```

But this is a list, and I need a bytesarry, which looks more like the one I mentioned above. Also to give a bigger picture: I want to send a bytestream of data to an ATTINY microcontroller and it cannot handle strings, only a bytestream.

Comment: possible duplicate of [hexadecimal string to byte array in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649407/hexadecimal-string-to-byte-array-in-python)

Comment: It looks to me like you're getting exactly what you want...a byte string created by deocding that hex string.  If you decode hex `77`, you get `119`, which happens to be ascii `w` and will display as such (e.g., if you `print b'\x77'` you will get `w`).