# Regex python expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to read a binary file.

My objective is to find all the matches of "10, 10, [any hex value exactly one time], either EE or DD]"

Thought I could do it like this:

```
pattern = (b"\x10\x10\[0-9a-fA-F]?\[xDD|xEE]")
```

Clearly not working. It seems that it becomes an error at the third part. I tried dissecting the statement and x10 and x11 works, but the rest just won't.

My understanding of "[0-9a-fA-F]?" is that it matches the range in the brackets 0 or 1 times. and the third part "xDD or xEE" am I wrong?

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please add, two examples of input ?

Comment: Seen [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13363076/1016065)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regex

```
b'\x10\x10.[\xdd\xee]'
```

A single `.` matches any character (any one-byte) single time, and a single `[ab]` matches `a` *or* `b` a single time.

---

```
>>> re.match(b'\x10\x10.[\xdd\xee]', b'\x10\x10\x00\xee')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match=b'\x10\x10\x00\xee'>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't the "." be like this "\x10\x10\." why no delimiter between the x10 and the dot?

Comment: Because the `.` is evaluated into a wild-card. `\.` is for matching strictly a dot character, as it serves as an escape sequence (and you want the wild card).

Comment: Many thanks! so in my last statement everything was correct except for | which shoulde have been turned into a \ hence seperating the both hex values inside the brackets?

Comment: `|` in your regex will make the last character need to match `\xee`, `\xdd` **or** `|` (pipe symbol). (structure of `[abc]` -> `a|b|c`)