# TypeError when using bytearrays

Tags: python

I am trying to read and write data through a PN532 module. I am using python 3.4.

```
import binascii
import sys
import struct
import Adafruit_PN532 as PN532

CS   = 18   
MOSI = 23 
MISO = 24
SCLK = 25       
CARD_KEY = [0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF]       
HEADER = b'BG'

pn532 = PN532.PN532(cs=CS, sclk=SCLK, mosi=MOSI, miso=MISO)
pn532.begin()
pn532.SAM_configuration()

print('PN532 NFC Module Writer'
print('== STEP 1 =========================')
print('Place the card to be written on the PN532...')
uid = pn532.read_passive_target()
while uid is None:
    uid = pn532.read_passive_target()
print('')
print('Found card with UID: 0x{0}'.format(binascii.hexlify(uid)))
print('')
print('==============================================================')
print('WARNING: DO NOT REMOVE CARD FROM PN532 UNTIL FINISHED WRITING!')
print('==============================================================')
print('')


print('== STEP 2 =========================')
block_choice = None
while block_choice is None:
    print('')
    block_choice = input('Enter user ID: ')
    try:
        block_choice = int(block_choice)
    except ValueError:
        print('Error! Unrecognized option.')
        continue
    if not (0 <= block_choice < 16777215):
        print('Error! User ID must be within 0 to 4294967295.')
        continue
    print('')
print('You chose the block type: {0}'.format(block_choice))
print('')

print('== STEP 3 =========================')
print('Confirm you are ready to write to the card:')
print('User ID: {0}'.format(block_choice))
choice = input('Confirm card write (Y or N)? ')
if choice.lower() != 'y' and choice.lower() != 'yes':
    print('Aborted!')
    sys.exit(0)
print('Writing card (DO NOT REMOVE CARD FROM PN532)...')

if not pn532.mifare_classic_authenticate_block(uid, 4, PN532.MIFARE_CMD_AUTH_B,
                                               CARD_KEY):
    print('Error! Failed to authenticate block 4 with the card.')
    sys.exit(-1)

data = bytearray(16)
# Add header
data[0:2] = HEADER
# Convert int to hex string with up to 6 digits
value = format(block_choice, 'x')
while (6 > len(value)):
    value = '0' + value
data[2:8] = value
# Finally write the card.
if not pn532.mifare_classic_write_block(4, data):
    print('Error! Failed to write to the card.')
    sys.exit(-1)
print('Wrote card successfully! You may now remove the card from the PN532.')
```

When I run this code I get the error "TypeError: can assign only bytes, buffers, or iterables of ints in range(0, 256). I believe this is an error with the data[2:8] line but I do not know how to fix it.

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/pi/Desktop/pn532_write.py", line 93 in 
     data[2:8] = value
TypeError: can assign only bytes, buffers, or iterables of ints in range(0, 256)

Comment: Almost certainly, this error message comes with a [stacktrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace) where you can exactly see what line has caused the problem. Can you post the stack trace as well?

Comment: Can you post full error message?

Comment: ive added it but ive had to write it in normal text

Comment: `value = '0' + value` means that value will be of type string. In order to assign a string to an byte array use `value.encode()`

Comment: this is starting to work but the code will not complete, ill let it run and see if it finally writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the following section:

```
value = format(block_choice, 'x')
while (6 > len(value)):
    value = '0' + value
data[2:8] = value
```

In this, you are setting `value` to be a string representation of a hexadecimal value and then while it has fewer than 6 characters you are prepending the string `"0"` to it.

The issue comes from the fact that you are then trying to assign this string (which represents a hexadecimal value but is still just a string) to the `data` bytearray.

[You can convert this hexadecimal string value that you have into bytes by using `bytes.fromhex()` or into a bytearray by using `bytearray.fromhex()`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649407/hexadecimal-string-to-byte-array-in-python/5682984)

To implement this in your code, you'd need to update the following line:

```
data[2:8] = value
```

to read as either of the following:

```
data[2:8] = bytes.fromhex(value)
data[2:8] = bytearray.fromhex(value)
```

Comment: what would the code for this look like? ive changed mine but im still getting the error

Comment: @R.Place I've added some clarification on how this should be implemented. I've done some testing locally and it fixes the issue as expected, at least for me.

Comment: i now get the error AssertionError: Data must be an array of 16 bytes

Comment: An `AssertionError` is usually cause by an `assert` statement, but it sounds like your original issue has been fixed and now you're running into a different issue entirely.

Comment: any idea on how i fix this?

Comment: I'd recommend following the stack trace that you get and trying to locate the source of the new error. Am I correct in saying that this answer has solved your original problem though?

Comment: you are correct yes. i do not understand how to fix this current issue though