# Python incorrectly converts between bytes and hex for me

Tags: python, hex, byte

I have an info_address that I want to convert to delimited hex

```
info_address_original = b'002dd748'
```

What i want is

```
info_address_coded = b'\x00\x2d\xd7\x48'
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649407/hexadecimal-string-to-byte-array-in-python)

```
info_address_original = b'002dd748'
info_address_intermediary = info_address_original.decode("utf-8") # '002dd748'
info_address_coded = bytes.fromhex( info_address_intermediary )   # b'\x00-\xd7H'
```

and i get

```
info_address_coded = b'\x00-\xd7H'
```

[What my debugger shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygUg0.png)

How would one go about correctly turning a bytes string like that to delimited hex? It worked implicitly in Python 2 but it doesn't work the way i would want in Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a representation of the bytes. `'-'` is the same as `'\x2d'`.

```
>>> b'\x00\x2d\xd7\x48' == b'\x00-\xd7H'
True
```

Answer (score 0):

The default representation of a byte string is to display the character value for all ascii printable characters and the encoded `\xhh` representation where `hh` is the hexadecimal value of the byte.

That means that `b'\x00\x2d\xd7\x48'` and `b'\x00-\xd7H' **are** the exact same string containing 4 bytes.