# convert the content of a file in hex to base64 and print out the result

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion, base64, hex

So i'm trying to create a very simple program that opens a file, read the file and convert what is in it from hex to base64 using python3.

I tried this :

```
file = open("test.txt", "r")
contenu = file.read()
encoded = contenu.decode("hex").encode("base64")
print (encoded)
```

but I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

I tried multiple other things but always get the same error.

inside the test.txt is :

```
4B
```

if you guys can explain me what I do wrong would be awesome.

Thank you

EDIT:
i should get `Sw==` as output

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Your code works for Python <= 2.7 but [needs updating in later versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5682984/4453817).

```
import base64
file = open("test.txt", "r")
contenu = file.read()
bytes = bytearray.fromhex(contenu)
encoded = base64.b64encode(bytes).decode('ascii')
print(encoded)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help! I get an error: TypeError: fromhex() argument must be str, not _io.TextIOWrapper

Comment: I've tested this code on Python 2.7.14 and 2.7.10 on Windows and Python 3.6.1 on Linux. All give the same result.

Comment: Please see https://www.onlinegdb.com/HJzq14MKm
This shows the code working under Python 3

Answer (score 0):

you need to encode hex string from file `test.txt` to bytes-like object using `bytes.fromhex()` before encoding it to base64.

```
import base64

with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
    content = file.read()
    encoded = base64.b64encode(bytes.fromhex(content))

print(encoded)
```

you should always use `with` statement for opening your file to automatically close the I/O when finished.

in IDLE:

```
>>>> import base64
>>>> 
>>>> with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
....     content = file.read()
....     encoded = base64.b64encode(bytes.fromhex(content))
....     
>>>> encoded
b'Sw=='
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but is does not work. I get this error : ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 2

Comment: @lucky_dandu ah sorry I'll edit it, i copy-pasted from string instead of loading a file... just a quick confirm: you're using python 3 right?

Comment: yes, i'm on ubuntu 16. i manage to right something that works on windows but not on ubuntu...

Comment: well it works on my python 3.5.2, i don't know how you got non-hexadecimal ValueError

Comment: @lucky_dandu does the answer work or do you get ValueError still?