# TypeError: from_buffer() cannot return the address of a unicode object

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, python-cffi, python-cryptography

While updating a tool to python3, I have been facing this issue on MacOS.

```
print(args.secret)
h = hmac.HMAC(args.secret.decode("hex"),hashes.SHA512(),backend=default_backend())
```

Output

```
39830c786a16

h = hmac.HMAC(hex(int(args.secret, 16)), hashes.SHA512(), backend=default_backend())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hmac.py", line 31, in __init__
    self._ctx = self._backend.create_hmac_ctx(key, self.algorithm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 202, in create_hmac_ctx
    return _HMACContext(self, key, algorithm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hmac.py", line 34, in __init__
    key_ptr = self._backend._ffi.from_buffer(key)
TypeError: from_buffer() cannot return the address of a unicode object
```

Possibly, it is an issue with the cryptography package. Some answers suggest reinstalling the cryptography package and its dependencies. (cffi, pycparser, six)

```
pip3 list
```

```
six             1.14.0
cryptography    2.8
pycparser       2.19
cffi            1.13.2
```

Still doesn't work. Has someone run into similar issues?

Comment: The key seems to be given as hexadecimal string. `hmacHMAC()` expects the key as bytes-like object, [here](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/mac/hmac/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hmac.HMAC). Under Python 3, it can be converted accordingly with `bytes.fromhex(args.secret)`, whereas `args.secret.decode("hex")` no longer works, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5682984). Thus, try `h = hmac.HMAC(bytes.fromhex(args.secret), hashes.SHA512(), backend=default_backend())`.

Comment: Yes, this worked!