# How to add hex bytes in a string?

Tags: python

I have this string of hex bytes, separated by spaces:

```
byteString = "7E 00 0A 01 01 50 01 00 48 65 6C 6C 6F"
```

How to add bytes in this way:

```
01 + 01 + 50 + 01 + 00 + 48 + 65 + 6C + 6C + 6F = 247
```

Comment: How is the original set of bytes stored? In a list of integers, a single string, etc?

Comment: string eg: "7E 00 0A 01 01 50 01 00 48 65 6C 6C 6F B8"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hexadecimal string to byte array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649407/hexadecimal-string-to-byte-array-in-python)

Comment: there is a conversion of hexadecimal string to byte array. There is no addition.

Comment: @thomas ***"there is a conversion"***: First you have cast, then you can add. You can't do math's with string objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you have the *hex* sequence as a *str* (*bytes*), what you need to do is:

- Split the sequence in smaller strings each representing a byte (2 *hex* digits): "*7E*", "*00*", ...
- Convert each such string to the integer value corresponding to the *hex* representation (the result will be a list of integers)
- Add the desired values (ignoring the 1<sup>st</sup> 3)

> ```py
> >>> byte_string = "7E 00 0A 01 01 50 01 00 48 65 6C 6C 6F"
> >>>
> >>> l = [int(i, 16) for i in byte_string.split(" ")]  # Split and conversion to int done in one step
> >>> l
> [126, 0, 10, 1, 1, 80, 1, 0, 72, 101, 108, 108, 111]
> >>>
> >>> [hex(i) for i in l]  # The hex representation of each element (for checking only)
> ['0x7e', '0x0', '0xa', '0x1', '0x1', '0x50', '0x1', '0x0', '0x48', '0x65', '0x6c', '0x6c', '0x6f']
> >>>
> >>> s = sum(l[3:])
> >>>
> >>> s
> 583
> >>> hex(s)
> '0x247'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tackle this in 2 parts - convert the string to a list of numbers, then sum the list. For this you can use the built-in [bytearray.fromhex](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray.fromhex) and [sum](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#sum) functions:

```
byteString = "7E 00 0A 01 01 50 01 00 48 65 6C 6C 6F"
numberList = bytearray.fromhex(byteString)
total = sum(numberList)
```