# Read text file that contains a single byte in hexadecimal in every line into bytearray

Tags: python, arrays

I have a file that contains bytes in plain text. For example:

```
00
01
02
A0
A1
A2
FD
FE
FF
```

I can read the file using:

```
fh = open(file, 'rb')
my_bytearray = bytearray(fh.read())
```

However, when I print this it returns:

```
print(my_bytearray)
b'00\r\n02\r\nA0\r\nA1\r\nA1\r\nA2\r\nFD\r\nFE\r\nFF'
```

It reads also the `\r\n` at the end of each line, and also not in hex format, for example not `\xFF` but `FF`.

I want to read this file into a bytearray and when I print this bytearray I want to see it as:

```
print(my_bytearray)
b'\x00\x01\x02\xA0\xA1\xA2\xFD\xFE\xFF'
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you been able to achieve so far, at which part are you stuck and what is the problem? Can you read all lines of a file into a list? Can you convert hexadecimal strings into numbers? Can you convert a list of numbers to a bytearray?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649407/hexadecimal-string-to-byte-array-in-python?

Comment: @mkrieger1 how can I combine the proposed solution with my problem? I also need to strip carriage return and new line, and then convert it to bytearray.

Comment: Have you tried to use `bytearray.from_hex(fh.read())`?

Comment: In general, you can strip carriage return and new line using the `.strip()` string method. But I don't think you need it here.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have tried `fromhex`, not `from_hex`. But it gave me an error, `TypeError: fromhex() argument must be str, not bytes`. EDIT: it works if I open the file with `r` only, not `rb`.