# splitting a string into a list of 2char strings

Tags: python, hex, ascii

I have a hex stream like: 1a2b3c4d5e6f7g but longer
I want to split it into 2char hex values in a list, and then convert them to ascii.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443967/how-to-create-python-bytes-object-from-long-hex-string

Comment: A "hex stream" including the character 'g' is a very interesting animal indeed.

Answer (score 5):

What about `binascii.unhexlify(hexstr)`?
See the docs for the binascii module : http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html

Comment: +1 `binascii.unhexlify('7573652062696e61736369692e756e6865786c696679')` gives
`'use binascii.unhexlify'`

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2.x you can use [`binascii.unhexlify`](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify):

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.unhexlify('abcdef0123456789')
'\xab\xcd\xef\x01#Eg\x89'
```

In Python 3 there's a more elegant method using only the built-in `bytes` type:

```
>>> bytes.fromhex('abcdef0123456789')
b'\xab\xcd\xef\x01#Eg\x89'
```

Comment: it seems to have also another name: a2b_hex        >>>binascii.a2b_hex('abcdef0123456789')      
Out[0]: '\xab\xcd\xef\x01#Eg\x89'

Answer (score 2):

One liner:

```
a = "1a2b3c"
print ''.join(chr(int(a[i] + a[i+1], 16)) for i in xrange(0, len(a), 2))
```

Explanation:

```
xrange(0, len(a), 2) # gives alternating indecis over the string
a[i] + a[i+1]        # the pair of characters as a string
int(..., 16)         # the string interpreted as a hex number
chr(...)             # the character corresponding to the given hex number
''.join()            # obtain a single string from the sequence of characters
```