# Hashing raw bytes in Python and Java produces different results

Tags: java, python, bytebuffer, hashlib, message-digest

I'm trying to **replicate the behavior of a Python 2.7 function in Java**, but I'm getting different results when running a (seemingly) identical sequence of bytes through a SHA-256 hash. The bytes are generated by manipulating a very large integer (exactly 2048 bits long) in a specific way (2nd line of my Python code example).

For my examples, the original 2048-bit integer is stored as `big_int` and `bigInt` in Python and Java respectively, and both variables contain the same number.

Python2 code I'm trying to replicate:

```
raw_big_int = ("%x" % big_int).decode("hex")

buff = struct.pack(">i", len(raw_big_int) + 1) + "\x00" + raw_big_int

pprint("Buffer contains: " + buff)
pprint("Encoded: " + buff.encode("hex").upper())

digest = hashlib.sha256(buff).digest()

pprint("Digest contains: " + digest)
pprint("Encoded: " + digest.encode("hex").upper())
```

Running this code prints the following (note that **the only result I'm actually interested in is the last one - the hex-encoded digest**. The other 3 prints are just to see what's going on under the hood):

```
'Buffer contains: \x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\xe3\xbb\xd3\x84\x94P\xff\x9c\'\xd0P\xf2\xf0s,a^\xf0i\xac~\xeb\xb9_\xb0m\xa2&f\x8d~W\xa0\xb3\xcd\xf9\xf0\xa8\xa2\x8f\x85\x02\xd4&\x7f\xfc\xe8\xd0\xf2\xe2y"\xd0\x84ck\xc2\x18\xad\xf6\x81\xb1\xb0q\x19\xabd\x1b>\xc8$g\xd7\xd2g\xe01\xd4r\xa3\x86"+N\\\x8c\n\xb7q\x1c \x0c\xa8\xbcW\x9bt\xb0\xae\xff\xc3\x8aG\x80\xb6\x9a}\xd9*\x9f\x10\x14\x14\xcc\xc0\xb6\xa9\x18*\x01/eC\x0eQ\x1b]\n\xc2\x1f\x9e\xb6\x8d\xbfb\xc7\xce\x0c\xa1\xa3\x82\x98H\x85\xa1\\\xb2\xf1\'\xafmX|\x82\xe7%\x8f\x0eT\xaa\xe4\x04*\x91\xd9\xf4e\xf7\x8c\xd6\xe5\x84\xa8\x01*\x86\x1cx\x8c\xf0d\x9cOs\xebh\xbc1\xd6\'\xb1\xb0\xcfy\xd7(\x8b\xeaIf6\xb4\xb7p\xcdgc\xca\xbb\x94\x01\xb5&\xd7M\xf9\x9co\xf3\x10\x87U\xc3jB3?vv\xc4JY\xc9>\xa3cec\x01\x86\xe9c\x81F-\x1d\x0f\xdd\xbf\xe8\xe9k\xbd\xe7c5'
'Encoded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
'Digest contains: Q\xf9\xb9\xaf\xe1\xbey\xdc\xfa\xc4.\xa9 \xfckz\xfeB\xa0>\xb3\xd6\xd0*S\xff\xe1\xe5*\xf0\xa3i'
'Encoded: 51F9B9AFE1BE79DCFAC42EA920FC6B7AFE42A03EB3D6D02A53FFE1E52AF0A369'
```

Now, below is my Java code so far. When I test it, I get the same value for the input buffer, but a different value for the digest. (`bigInt` contains a `BigInteger` object containing the same number as `big_int` in the Python example above)

```
byte[] rawBigInt = bigInt.toByteArray();

ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(rawBigInt.length + 4);
buff.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
buff.putInt(rawBigInt.length).put(rawBigInt);

System.out.print("Buffer contains: ");
System.out.println( DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(buff.array()) );


MessageDigest hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
hash.update(buff);
byte[] digest = hash.digest();

System.out.print("Digest contains: ");
System.out.println( DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(digest) );
```

Notice that in my Python example, I started the buffer off with `len(raw_big_int) + 1` packed, where in Java I started with just `rawBigInt.length`. I also omitted the extra 0-byte (`"\x00"`) when writing in Java. I did both of these for the same reason - in my tests, calling `toByteArray()` on a `BigInteger` returned a `byte` array **already beginning with a 0-byte** that was exactly 1 byte longer than Python's byte sequence. So, at least in my tests, `len(raw_big_int) + 1` equaled `rawBigInt.length`, since `rawBigInt` began with a 0-byte and `raw_big_int` did not.

Alright, that aside, here is the Java code's output:

```
Buffer contains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
Digest contains: E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855
```

As you can see, the buffer contents appear the same in both Python and Java, but the digests are obviously different. Can someone point out where I'm going wrong?

I suspect it has something to do with the strange way Python seems to store bytes - the variables `raw_big_int` and `buff` show as type `str` in the interpreter, and when printed out by themselves have that strange format with the '\x's that is *almost* the same as the bytes themselves in some places, but is utter gibberish in others. I don't have enough Python experience to understand exactly what's going on here, and my searches have turned up fruitless.

Also, since I'm trying to port the Python code into Java, I can't just change the Python - my goal is to write Java code that takes the same input and produces the same output. I've searched around ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554946/android-java-method-equivalent-to-python-hmac-sha256-in-hex) in particular seemed related) but didn't find anything to help me out. Thanks in advance, if for nothing else than for reading this long-winded question! :)

Comment: Who downvoted this question? Honestly, I have no idea what questions would pass muster with you if this one doesn't. My mind is boggled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, you've got the data in the buffer, but the cursor positions are all wrong. After you've written your data to the ByteBuffer it looks like this, where the *x*'s represent your data and the *0*'s are unwritten bytes in the buffer:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    ^ position                               ^ limit
```

The cursor is positioned after the data you've written. A read at this point will read from `position` to `limit`, which is the bytes you haven't written.

Instead, you want this:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
^ position          ^ limit
```

where the position is 0 and the limit is the number of bytes you've written. To get there, call [`flip()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#flip--). Flipping a buffer conceptually switches it from write mode to read mode. I say "conceptually" because ByteBuffers don't have explicit read and write modes, but you should think of them as if they do.

(The opposite operation is [`compact()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#compact--), which goes back to read mode.)

Comment: you need to mention also that `buff.array()` is the entire buffer backing array, not just what has been written which might be different things.

Comment: In this case, I allocated the ByteBuffer with exactly the size of the data I put into it, so the backing array ended up being the same size - before I didn't quite understand the way the buffer treated its backing array, but it makes much more sense now. Thanks!