# Send a packet of data literally via UDP in Python

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, networking

I want to my UDP data packet to have literately this information for example:

```
data = "83053163021478010102010370020000000000"
```

I'm using the follow code to send it which works fine(I can see it going out on wireshark):

```
listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
listener.sendto(data, (IP, PORT))
```

When I look at the data packet in wireshark i want the (wireshark)data packet == data. How do I declare/convert the data type to make this happen.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to convert the hexadecimal values in the data into raw binary? Otherwise I don't understand the question

Comment: data is a hex string represented as ascii string. I want listener.sendto(data, (IP, PORT)) to send data as the literal hex bytes that the data string equals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
import codecs
data = codecs.decode("83053163021478010102010370020000000000", "hex_codec")
```

Then you can send `data` same as you are doing now.

ref: [How to create python bytes object from long hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443967/how-to-create-python-bytes-object-from-long-hex-string)

Comment: hcs, Thank you so much this works perfect and was exactly what I was trying to do. You have no idea how thankful I am for your answer!