# Perl unpack to Python Conversion

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, hex, unpack

I'm struggling myself to replicate the below statement from Perl to Python but I'm not really sure how to perform using the python struct module.

So the code that I need to convert is:

```
my $hex_string = "DEADBEEF";
my @bytes = map( hex, unpack("(A2)*", $hex_string ) );
```

The above is equivalent to

```
my @bytes = ( 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF );
```

`A2` doesn't seems to be a good option for Python struct. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `unpack("(A2)*", $s)` splits the string in `$s` into two-character strings. `$s =~ /..?/sg` would be equivalent.

Comment: By the way, `map( hex, unpack("(A2)*", $hex_string) )` is better written as `unpack "C*", pack "H*", $hex_string`

Comment: Duplicate of [How to create python bytes object from long hex string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443967/how-to-create-python-bytes-object-from-long-hex-string?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `int` with `base` argument to convert hexadecimal number string to `int`:

```
>>> int('15', base=16)
21
```

---

```
>>> val = 15
>>> int(str(val), base=16)
21
```

**UPDATE**

To use [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack), first conver the `hex_string` to binary data using [`binascii.unhexlify`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify) (or [`binascii.a2b_hex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.a2b_hex)):

```
>>> import struct, binascii
>>> hex_string = "DEADBEEF"
>>> binascii.unhexlify(hex_string)  # Hexa decimal -> binary data
'\xde\xad\xbe\xef'

>>> struct.unpack('4B', binascii.unhexlify(hex_string))  # 4 = 8 / 2
(222, 173, 190, 239)
>>> struct.unpack('4B', binascii.unhexlify(hex_string)) == (0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF)
True
>>> struct.unpack('{}B'.format(len(hex_string) // 2), binascii.unhexlify(hex_string))
(222, 173, 190, 239)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm :)

Comment: @ikegami, Thank you for your feedback. I will study `unpack` in Perl and update the answer.

Comment: @ikegami, I updated the answer accordingly. Thank you.